# LoadError on Installing Rails via Cygwin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, cygwin

I am trying to instal rails on Windows XP to do the Ruby on Rails Tutorial but attemtpting to install rails, I am getting this error:

```
Marlon@DevComputer ~/rubygems-1.8.15 
$ gem install rails C:\Ruby192\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- /cygdrive/c/Ruby192/bin/gem (LoadError)
```

Any help? All the links I am finding so far on Google search does not solve the issue. Any solution?

Comment: installing Ruby from the cygwin setup kinda solved this. Because I installed Ruby 1.9.3p0, I am having another problem on the "missing psych (for YAML output)"

Answer (score 0):

Try using [RailsInsraller](http://railsinstaller.org/). I use it, and it works like a charm. It also come bundled with a  lot of other useful software for Rails dev.

Comment: I tried that but didn't work. I solved the issue by installing Ruby from the Cygwin setup (then installed Ruby Gems & Rails). I am not sure how installing Ruby on Cygwin setup was related to my problem but it worked. I, then, updated Ruby to 1.9.3.p0. I also solved the "missing psych (for YAML output)" (see my comment on my original question).

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of RailsInstaller? That version might have fixed your errors. Also, the error in the question, was it from Railsinstaller?